# Angular $http POST escaping nested objects

Tags: angularjs

So, I am 100% certain I am missing something obvious here but I've tried everything I can think of. I'm attempting to setup a simple $http POST request in angular:

```
$http({
      url: 'http://api.local.com/sign_in.json',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      params: test5
    })
```

I'm attempting to send in an object that has a key of 'user' and a value of another object which has two key value pairs (email and password) as can be seen below:

```
var temp2 = {
  'user': {
    'email': 'test@test.com',
    'password': 'testing'
  }
};

var test5 = {'user':{'email':'test@test.com','password':'testing'}};
```

However, when I posted any of the versions I've tried (which are far more than what's shown above), I receive a response from the server of:

```
Started POST "/sign_in.json?user=%7B%22email%22:%22test@test.com%22,%22password%22:%22testing%22%7D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-02 16:22:58 -0500
Processing by V1::SessionsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"user"=>"{\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"password\":\"testing\"}"}
```

The first level 'user' key comes in correct, however the entire nested object that's the value of the 'user' key are escaped.

If I change the var test5 = { 'user' : 'test' }, the parameters come in correctly so the issue is the nested object. I need the parameters to come in as:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"email":"test@test.com","password":"testing"}}
```

not:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>"{\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"password\":\"testing\"}"}
```

Been a bit of a long day so apologies if I am missing something super obvious here. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify(test5)` ?

Comment: @jonkroll JSON.stringify(test5) comes to the server as Parameters: {"0"=>"{", "1"=>"\"", "10"=>"e", "11"=>"m", "12"=>"a", "13"=>"i", "14"=>"l", "15"=>"\"", "16"=>":", "17"=>"\"", "18"=>"t", "19"=>"e", "2"=>"u", "20"=>"s", "21"=>"t", "22"=>"@", "23"=>"t", "24"=>"e", "25"=>"s", "26"=>"t", "27"=>".", "28"=>"c", "29"=>"o", "3"=>"s", "30"=>"m", "31"=>"\"", "32"=>",", "33"=>"\"", "34"=>"p", "35"=>"a", "36"=>"s", "37"=>"s", "38"=>"w", "39"=>"o", "4"=>"e", "40"=>"r", "41"=>"d", "42"=>"\"", "43"=>":", "44"=>"\""...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `params` your `test5` is url encoded and appears in the URL. Since you are sending user info you probably want to use `data` instead of `params`.

```
$http({
    url: 'http://api.local.com/sign_in.json',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: test5
})
```

Also note that single quotes is not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Jasen. I changed over to data and now it's sending an OPTIONS request to the server. I read up on that a bit but I think if I can handle the OPTIONS request server-side the data should come in correct. Also thanks for the tips on the valid JSON!